# How to plot a point on a function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot a point on a graph of a function. I've seen `gnuplot> plot “< echo ‘x   y’”` as an example, however, that only works on the terminal and I need it to be on a .gp file. I've also seen doing `set parametric plot 4,3` but then I can't plot the point over the graph of the function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output 'plot.eps'

set xr[-10:10]
set yr[-2:2]
plot sin(x), \
 "<echo '3.141592 0'" pt 7 ps 2 notitle
```

The comma allows you to plot multiple things in the same plot.  This way you have to specify the range and the point position manually, but it works for me in a plot script in gnuplot 4.6.

Comment: This doesn't really matter, but you don't need the single quote inside the double quotes.  i.e. `"< echo 3.14159 0"` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use 'inline data'

```
plot sin(x) w lines, '-' w p pt 7 ps 5
   3.14 0
e
```